# return a string from a function in C

Tags: c, string, return, return-value

I am learning C and I want to implement a function that returns to main function a string. I have read some topics here but I got confused.. I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char myPrint(int); 

int main()
{ 
   char msg[10];

   msg = myPrint(1);

   printf("\n %s \n", msg); 
} 

char myPrint(int n)
{ 
   char msg[10];

   if(n==1)
      strcpy(msg, "ACCEPT");
   else
      strcpy(msg, "DENY");

   return msg;
}
```

and I get a bunch of warnings and error.. I read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) for the usage of the strcpy 
and many others links relevant to this topic but I didn’t get it..

Comment: Instead of ignoring your warnings and errors, it is helpful to read them and analyze them to understand what you're doing wrong so you can do it right next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of advice: returning a pointer to a string when that string is defined as a local variable in the function won't work, as the allocated memory for the string will be unvalidated.

If your function returns literal strings, as per your example, you have to do as **Acme** said:

```
char *MyPrint (int n)
{
  if (n==1)
    return "ACCEPT";
  else
    return "DENY";
}
```

As you are returning a pointer to char, you cannot assign that pointer to an array, as you try to do in `main()`. You have to assign it to a variable that must be a pointer to char as well:

```
int main()
{ 
   char *msg;

   msg = myPrint(1);    
   printf("\n %s \n", msg); 
   return 0;
}
```

If you need to copy the resulting string to an array, then you must use `strcpy()` (or better yer, `strncpy()` ) as this:

```
int main()
{ 
   char msg[10];

   strcpy (msg, myPrint(1) ); /* providing that your function won't ever return a string longer than 9 chars, or bad things will happen */
   printf("\n %s \n", msg); 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare your function as

```
char *myPrint(int n);
```

Do not return the local variable `msg` from your function - it ceases to exist after `myPrint` function.

```
 if(n==1)
     return "ACCEPT";
 else
     return  "DENY";
```

Comment: ok but i get this now
`10:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[10]’ from type ‘char *’`

Comment: That is because char * is not the same as char[10]. If you declare myPrint as having return value of char[10] this error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You should never return a pointer to variable that is allocated in the function, because by the time it returns, the variable will be de-allocated automatically (it is stack-allocated as opposed to heap-allocated or static). So instead, you pass in a char * to myPrint and fill the char array from inside it. Then the outer function that declared the char array can access it without error. Note though that the following is still not best practice, because it allows for buffer overruns when one passes in a pointer to an array that is shorter than length of "ACCEPT" + 1 (+1 for terminating \0 character).

```
void myPrint(char *msg, int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        strcpy(msg, "ACCEPT");
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(msg, "DENY");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char msg[10];
    myPrint(msg, 1);
    printf("\n %s \n", msg); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function as

```
char *myPrint(char *ptr, int n);
```

to return string from your function.
Call it from your `main` function as

```
printf("\n %s \n", myPrint(msg, 1));
```

Your function

```
char *myPrint(char *msg, int n)
{ 
    if(n==1)
         strcpy(msg, "ACCEPT");
    else
         strcpy(msg, "DENY");

    return msg;
}
```

But in this case there is no need to return string from your function as it will update your `msg` array in `main`.

Comment: See the update. You cannot return pointer to local variable. You have to pass an address to your function.

Comment: Now please explain why downvote? He wanted to return pointer from his function.

Comment: @Nat95; Thanks :). I suggest you to use debugger to debug your program. This will help you to catch these type of errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_SIZE 10

char * myPrint(const int ); 

int main()
{ 
    char *msg = NULL;

    msg = myPrint(1);

    free(myPrint(1));

    printf("\n %s \n", msg);

    return 0;
} 

char * myPrint(const int n)
{ 
    char *msg = (char *) malloc(STR_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    if (n == 1)
        strcpy(msg, "ACCEPT");
    else
        strcpy(msg, "DENY");

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: -1: Why are you allocating msg in 'main' first, then overwrite it with the newly allocated buffer from 'myPrint'? And then you don't even free the buffers. And you don't check for unsuccesful 'malloc'.

Comment: Because if I don't allocate it in 'myPrint' program gives segmentation fault.

Comment: The first allocation in main is completely useless and gives you unreachable memory when you overwrite the pointer to it with the return value from 'myPrint'!

Comment: Ok no problem let's initialize it in main with _NULL_, but you have to allocate it in 'myPrint'. Otherwise program gives segmentation fault, because it doesn't know how many bytes allocate to the string!

Comment: Seriously? free(myPrint(1)) ? Please don't post this kind of non-sense. You clearly have no understanding of how this stuff works.

Comment: Ok, let's speak about your code, why your function doesn't return a string in your answer to the question?

Comment: My answer does what was asked in a slightly different way. Yours has some fundamental flaws, which I pointed out.